# How do I twist a curve (by rotating a segment)?

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

I have already searched everywhere but those threads are about making rope-like objects.

I am trying to animate start and end values of a curve's geometry. But I want it to twist midway. I am trying  to rotate it's segment on Y axis as in the image but it is not working.

[image: expected twist]

Here on the left is what I want to achieve and right is what I have. I tried rotating the segment/vertex on Y axis but its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the Tilt (<kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd>) function.